# Dimension range for non-torsion homotopy groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds, cw-complexes

Is there a constant $c$ for which the following is true?

*Let $X$ be a connected finite CW complex of dimension $d$. For any $i>cd$, the homotopy group $\pi_i(X)$ is torsion.*

What if we replace finite CW complex with (smooth) connected manifold?

Comment: No.  For example, take the space $S^2 \vee S^2$.   Or I suppose the answer would be yes, if you alow $c=\infty$.  The answer remains no for manifolds, since $S^2 \vee S^2$ has the homotopy-type of a manifold with boundary. And you can make it a wedge summand of the 3-skeleton of a closed 4-manifold.

Comment: If a space has only finitely many nontrivial rational homotopy groups, it is called rationally elliptic. In some sense most spaces aren't rationally elliptic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_homotopy_theory#Elliptic_and_hyperbolic_spaces. For example, simply-connected elliptic spaces have nonnegative Euler characteristic.

Comment: To expand on Igor's comment, spaces with finitely many rational homotopy groups, from the perspective of the Postnikov tower for the space, are analogous to series with finitely many non-zero terms, with spaces analogous to all series.    That gives you a sense for the relative proportion of spaces one would be seeing.

Comment: Here is a basic source of examples. Take your favorite closed simply-connected even-dimensional manifold $F$ with zero Euler characteristic, e.g. $S^3\times S^3$, take any closed simply-connected manifold $M$, and start taking iterated connected sums $M\# F\#...\# F$. Each connected sum with $F$ lowers the Euler characteristic by $2$, so eventually  the Euler characteristic becomes negative and hence the result is not rationally elliptic. For example, $F\# F$ is not rationally elliptic.